how to add a dataframe that rows are valid for a period of time with featuretools
I am working on a dataset with multiple tables. I am using featuretools library for feature engineering. One of the tables that is NOT the target dataframe, comes with several columns. Three of the column are related to the conversation: ['rating', 'valid_from', 'valid_to']. I use valid_from as the time_index but am not sure how to incorporate valid_to column. If this was the target dataframe I could have used valid_to as cutoffs but since it's not the target dataframe I don't know how to set up the problem so there is no data leakage.
I also thought of using valid_to as the time_index but again I am not sure how to incorporate valid_from column in that case.
